# travar R ao redimensionar a janela

Tags: android, redimensionamento

No `R`, é possível pegar e travar (hold) um device, desenhar uma imagem e fazer o flush do render gráfico. Isso é útil para situações de telas complexas com centenas de pontos e/ou gradientes de cor, já que sem fazer o hold o dispositivo seria atualizado a cada operação que modifica a tela, e essa travada no dispositivo funciona normalmente.

Porém, contudo, todavia, qualquer operação de redimensionamento da janela vai causar uma atualização do dispositivo, mas sem travar e fazer o flush.

Existe alguma forma de falar para o `R` travar a tela (colocar com hold) para operações de redimensionamento?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para impedir o redesenho durante o redimensionamento, você pode usar dev.control("inhibit"), apesar de que enquanto estiver com o status de inhibit você não vai conseguir fazer o redraw ou o flush.